# Non standard evaluation setting names R

Tags: r, purrr, nse, quosure, seurat

I am trying to repeatedly call a function (specifically Seurat::DimPlot), where one of the the arguments is a named list (cells.highlight).  I am planning to use `purrr::imap` to do make the call.  I have a named list, where each of the element of the list is a vector of characters.  I would like to create the list for the cells.highlight argument of Seurat::DimPlot.  When I tried

```
imap(mylist, ~ DimPlot(seurat_obj, cells.highlight=list(.y=.x), cols="lightgrey", 
  cols.highlight="dodgerblue")  )
```

The plot looks nice, but the instead of replacing the variable .y with the list element name, it leaves the list element name as ".y".  (So on the plot I see ".y" in the legend). To Make a SSCE

```
dp <- function(name, values){
   list(name = values)
}
dp("a",paste0("a",1:3))
# $name
# [1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
```

where I want it to be

```
$a
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3"`
```

I've tried using enquo, as_name, using ':=', ensym, quote, but I just can't seem to get it right.  I know you can break this into two lines with something like list[[name]]=..., but because this is part of a larger problem, I would love to learn how to appropriately quote and unquote the variable name.

I've always had trouble using NSE, even after reading, re-reading, and re-reading Hadley Wickhams' Advanced-R [chapter on quasiquotations](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) and his [chapter on evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html), but it appears that all the pieces are there, I just can't put them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are usinr `purrr` you should use `set_names` to set the names of your list

```
imap(mylist, ~ DimPlot(seurat_obj, cells.highlight=set_names(list(.x), .y), cols="lightgrey", 
  cols.highlight="dodgerblue")  )
```

With the `dp` example, it would be

```
dp <- function(name, values){
  set_names(list(values), name)
}
dp("a",paste0("a",1:3))
# $`a`
# [1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
```

So in this case this really doesn't have anything to do with non-standard evaluation. It's just about using the right function for the job.

Comment: I really hate when I get so fixated on seeing a problem one way that I miss an obvious answer.  I guess when your only tool is a hammer, everything starts looking like a nail.  Thanks for the new tool!